# How to prevent Excel from formatting numbers stored in variables as dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this subroutine `computeTotal()` that computes the sum of differences between cells in column E and column B (times in column E are greater/later than times in column B):

```
Sub computeTotal():
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim total As Double
    i = 2
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value)
        total = total + DateDiff("n", Range("B" & i).Value, Range("E" & i).Value)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Debug.Print ("total: " & total) ' prints 2, as expected
    
    Range("G2") = total ' enters 1/2/1900 (and recently 1/2/1900  12:00:00 AM) into cell G2
    Range("H2") = 2080 - total ' enters 9/8/1905 into cell H2
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get it to stick the value of `total` in cell G2 (Ideally, I want it to be the amount of hours logged between all the cells in columns E and B, but right now I'm working with minutes) and `2080 -` the value of `total` in cell H2, but it keeps trying to format `total` and `2080 - total` as dates. I know about putting an apostrophe before numbers to prevent Excel (VBA) from converting them to dates, but how can one do this when a variable is involved?

I tried doing `Range("G2") = CDbl(total)` without any luck.

Comment: Ensure your target cell is formatted as `General` (or `Number` if you prefer). In VBA you can use the `NumberFormat` property of the `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert it as number

Range("G2").NumberFormat = "##0"